# JavaScript localStorage Variable Not Updating as Expected

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm working on a JavaScript project where I need to dynamically update a list of selected muscles and display associated exercises. However, I've encountered an issue where the selectedMuscles variable, which is supposed to represent the user-selected muscles, is not updating as expected.
I have a function called createWorkoutSplit that is responsible for generating a workout split based on the selected muscles stored in the localStorage. Here's a simplified version of the code:
The issue is that when I log the selectedMuscles variable within the createWorkoutSplit function, it always displays the initial value from localStorage even if I change the selection or leave it empty.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  const tableBody = document.querySelector("#workout-split tbody");

  function createWorkoutSplit() {
    tableBody.innerHTML = ""; // Clear existing content

    // Retrieve selected muscles from localStorage
    const selectedMuscles = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("selectedMuscles")) || [];

    // Log selectedMuscles for debugging
    console.log("Selected Muscles:", selectedMuscles);

    // Rest of the code to generate the workout split based on selectedMuscles
    // ...
  }

  // ...

  // Initial call to createWorkoutSplit
  createWorkoutSplit();
});
```

I expect selectedMuscles to update based on user interactions. For example, if a user selects "Chest" and "Back," selectedMuscles should contain ["Chest", "Back"], but it always shows the initial value even if I change the selection.I'm using localStorage to store and retrieve the selected muscles.
The selection of muscles is done in another part of the application, and I ensure that I update localStorage correctly.
What I've Tried:

I've checked that the localStorage updates correctly when I select or deselect muscles, so the issue seems to be related to how I'm retrieving and using the selectedMuscles variable within the createWorkoutSplit function.

I appreciate any insights into what might be causing this issue and how I can ensure that selectedMuscles is updated based on user interactions. Thank you for your help!

Comment: const savedMuscles = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("selectedMuscles"));

Comment: don't have it 
if u wanna contact me and give you my code

Comment: i want the muscles to be saved in a local storage and based on it when opening another page it shows a table of the selected muscles